# Further refining list in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup 4 to get various results from a web page. Currently I am trying to process a list of URLs and have BS go out and get a div from these pages and store this in a new list. I am successful at doing this. The next step would be to get the text result of the div but getting it to successfully iterate over this list and further refine the results isn't successful for me.

I end up with a list called `dealcomments` which I try to iterate through the index values while performing a dealcomments[i].find('a').text on it. Im just unsure on how to further process the list to refine it.

```
def getDealComments(deallinks):
dealcomments = []

# Can't modify dealcomments to get plain text :~(
for index,link in enumerate(deallinks):
    source = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    dealcomments.append(soup.find_all('div', class_='posttext'))
      
    print(len(dealcomments))
return dealcomments
```

This will successfully generate a list of 80 items but I cannot figure out a way to take this refine it to the text.

If I run:

```
print(dealcomments.find('a').text)
```

back in the main function it gives an error.

Here is an example of the "posttext" div that I get back:

```
[<div class="posttext" style="margin:20px 0px 10px 0px;display:block;margin-bottom:50px;"><a href="/j/4/?pid=1494475&amp;lno=1&amp;tid=11000&amp;afsrc=1" target="_blank">Amazon</a> has All-new Kindle Paperwhite Now Waterproof on sale. Shipping is free.
<ul>
<li><a href="/j/4/?pid=1494475&amp;lno=1&amp;tid=11000&amp;afsrc=1" target="_blank">All-new Kindle Paperwhite (8GB)</a> for <b>$89.99</b></li>
<li><a href="/j/4/?pid=1494475&amp;lno=2&amp;tid=11000&amp;afsrc=1" target="_blank">All-new Kindle Paperwhite (32GB)</a> for <b>$114.99</b></li>
<li><a href="/j/4/?pid=1494475&amp;lno=3&amp;tid=11000&amp;afsrc=1" target="_blank">All-new Kindle - Now with a Built-in Front Light</a> <b>$65</b></li>
<li><b>YMMV</b>: 15% off a Kindle Paperwhite + $20 ebook credit with promo code "<strong>READKINDLE00</strong>".
```

I am trying to get all the readable text in the "posttext" div.

Comment: well you're trying to `find` in a list

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
def getDealComments(deallinks):
 dealcomments = []

# Can't modify dealcomments to get plain text :~(
 for index,link in enumerate(deallinks):
    source = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='posttext'):
        dealcomments.append(item.text)


 return dealcomments
```

Comment: This appeared to work like a charm, text seems to be exactly what I need, your help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: If your questions are answered you really need to accept them.